# Package org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc does not exist

Tags: maven, jdbc, apache-flink

I want to use the JDBC connector in an Apache Flink application. But maven doesn't find the flink JDBC package.
I added the following dependency to my pom.xml in the "build-jar" section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The jar files were downloaded by maven and are available in the local maven directory.
My code looks like this.

```
// standard, not relevant flink imports
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCOutputFormat;


public class BatchLayerExec {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {

        //Definition of Strings for the connection to the database

        try {
            ExecutionEnvironment environment = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

            final TypeInformation<?>[] fieldTypes =
                    new TypeInformation<?>[] { ... };

            final RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypes);

            //Define Input Format Builder
            JDBCInputFormat.JDBCInputFormatBuilder inputBuilder = JDBCInputFormat
                .buildJDBCInputFormat()
                .setDrivername(driverName)
                .setDBUrl(dbURL + sourceDB)
                .setQuery(selectQuery)
                .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
                .setUsername(dbUser)
                .setPassword(dbPassword)
                .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo);

            DataSet<Row> sourceTable = environment.createInput(inputBuilder.finish());
 
            // Transformation
            // ...

            // Print for debugging
            transformedTable.print();

            // Output transformed data to output table
            //Define Output Format Builder
            JDBCOutputFormat.JDBCOutputFormatBuilder outputBuilder = JDBCOutputFormat
                    .buildJDBCOutputFormat()
                    .setDrivername(driverName)
                    .setDBUrl(dbURL + sourceDB)
                    .setQuery(insertQuery)
                    .setSqlTypes(new int[] { ... })
                    .setUsername(dbUser)
                    .setPassword(dbPassword);

            //Define dataSink
            transformedTable.output(outputBuilder.finish());

            environment.execute();

        } catch(final Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But during the build process with `mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar`, I get the error message:
`package org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc does not exist`.
I removed some not relevant definitions and steps in the code (see comments). Please comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the package `org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc` is deprecated.
**Importing the package `org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc` works.**

**EDIT**

Note that this requires changing the `JDBCInputFormat` and `JDBCOutputFormat` classes to `JdbcInputFormat` and `JdbcOutputFormat`.